# Неправильное обтекание картинки

Tags: css, вёрстка, float, img

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста почему при обтекании картинки `border` получается как бы в ней. Мне нужно чтобы `border` был возле текста, можно конечно просто прописать `margin`, но может есть какой-то более правильный способ? 
Подскажите. Заранее спасибо

```css
img{
float:left;
width:300px;
}
ul{
 list-style: none;
 width: 700px;
}
 ul li{
 border-left: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img  src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/56aec6c2848cf1529ab867ef.png" alt="">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
    <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
    <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
    <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` плавает, а список  - нет.

Отправьте список в плавание

```
ul{ float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно убрать ширину у списка и задать `overflow: hidden;`

```css
img{
float:left;
width:300px;
}
ul{
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
 ul li{
 border-left: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img  src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/56aec6c2848cf1529ab867ef.png" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
      <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
      <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
      <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Или обернуть все содержимое (а обернуть все необходимо т.к. присутствует плавающий элемент) и задать списку тоже `float`:

```css
img{
float:left;
width:300px;
}
ul{
 list-style: none;
 width: 700px;
  float: left;
}
 ul li{
 border-left: 4px solid black;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<img  src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/56aec6c2848cf1529ab867ef.png" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
      <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
      <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
      <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Вариант с `flex` и оберткой:

```css
img{
float:left;
width:300px;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 700px;
}
 ul li{
   border-left: 4px solid black;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<img  src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/56aec6c2848cf1529ab867ef.png" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
      <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
      <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
      <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо чтобы элементы списка, лежащие ниже изображения, растягивались на всю ширину контейнера, то просто добавить `overflow: hidden;` элементам списка:

```css
img{
float:left;
width:300px;
}
ul{
 list-style: none;
 width: 700px;
}
 ul li{
 border-left: 4px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<img  src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/56aec6c2848cf1529ab867ef.png" alt="">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
    <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
    <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <h3>-Как поднятся в топ?</h3>
    <p>Что бы подняться в ТОП нужно бла бла бла. А лучше обратиться к нам! Заполните заявку сейс и получите скидку 10% на первое бла бла бла. Мы поможем вам улучшить производительность и настроим бла бла бла </p>
   </li>
  </ul>
```